# How to solve complicated floor function equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have been thinking about solving equations involving several groups of floor functions.  My research on solving floor function equations has only shown sums of individual floors, such as:

$\lfloor f(x) \rfloor + \lfloor g(x) \rfloor + \lfloor h(x) \rfloor = \lfloor i(x) \rfloor$

However, I have not found an example in which there are floors multiplied together, such as:

$\lfloor f(x) \rfloor \lfloor g(x) \rfloor + \lfloor h(x) \rfloor \lfloor i(x) \rfloor = 0$

I cannot figure out how to solve such a problem.  As an example, I have the equation:

$\Bigl\lfloor \sqrt{2x + \frac{1}{2}} \Bigr \rfloor \lfloor x \rfloor -
\frac{1}{2} \Bigl \lfloor \frac{\sqrt{8x} - 1}{2} \Bigr \rfloor^2 \Bigl \lfloor \sqrt{2x + \frac{1}{2}} \Bigr \rfloor - 
\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\sqrt{8x} - 1}{2} \right) \left( \sqrt{2x + \frac{1}{2}} \right) - P = 0$

I have attempted to break this into pieces, and set them equal to each other, however, the solutions which I have found do not seem to relate to one another, and do not give me an overall solution.  What should I do?

Comment: to my knowledge, there is no standard way of dealing with floor multiplication, unless of lucky "combinations", which doe not look to happen in your particular problem

Comment: If $$\lfloor f(x) \rfloor \lfloor g(x) \rfloor + \lfloor h(x) \rfloor \lfloor i(x) \rfloor = 0$$then$$ \lfloor f(x) \rfloor \lfloor g(x) \rfloor = - \lfloor h(x) \rfloor \lfloor i(x) \rfloor$$$$\implies \frac { \lfloor f(x) \rfloor \lfloor g(x) \rfloor}{ \lfloor h(x) \rfloor \lfloor i(x) \rfloor}=-1$$Feels like a number theory problem...

Comment: You can rewrite your equation into a system of equations of the single cases.